# table storing flag or parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a demographics table and an Employee table, each of which have a Gender Column containing values like M, F, and U. There is another table named Parameter which provides a description and field name for those values i.e.:

```
Description    Field_name  Value
Male             DEMCD      M
Female           DEMCD      F
Unknown          DEMCD      U 
Male             EMPDC      M
Female           EMPDC      F
```

There are several instances where those values are used in other tables besides the demographic table (e.g. employee table). Is there a way I could find what field name is tagged to what table, and the name of that table?

Comment: To clarify the problen please show Employee table structure and sample data.

Comment: @ConradFrix  tried running the query you provided and received an error  :Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL Server, you can find tables in sys.tables and columns in sys.columns.  As an example, you can use a query like this to search for columns wherever they exist (this assumes the columns have something consistent in the name):

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
        AND c.name LIKE '%YourColumnName%'
```

You could also tie it to your parameter table with this criteria, if all the field names exist there:

```
AND c.name IN (SELECT DISTINCT Field_name FROM Parameter)
```

If you wish to be able to select from the tables you find, you can add a column like this to your select clause:

```
'SELECT * FROM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + '] WHERE [' + c.name + '] IN (''Value1'',''Value2'')' AS select_code_val
```

You can copy/paste and run this manually, run it as dynamic sql within a larger stored procedure, etc.

Comment: ok that solved half of the prob, but how do i know  field name is associated to those tables?

Comment: That's where the join between sys.tables and sys.columns comes in.  This query displays the table that contains the columns meeting the search criteria.

Comment: Great, i have one last question. is there a way i could find if the column has hard-coded values i.e Gender column has M,F,U or State column includes all the states ?

Comment: You would have to select directly from the table/column in question to do that.  See my updated answer for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the list of objects that have a specified column

```
    select so.name from sys.objects so inner join sys.columns sc 
on so.object_id = sc.object_id
where sc.name = 'yourcolumnname'
```